# Aristarchus and the Moon's distance

Tags: algebra-precalculus

I'm trying to plug the number into the equation below, but I'm getting 67 earth radii instead of 60 radii. What am I getting wrong?

http://www.phy6.org/stargaze/Shipprc2.htm

> Let $R$ be the radius of that circle and $T$ the time it takes the Moon to go around once, about one month. In that time the Moon covers a distance of $2\pi R$
>
> An eclipse of the Moon occurs when the Moon passes through the shadow of the Earth, on the opposite side from the Sun (therefore, we must be seeing a full Moon). If $r$ is the radius of the Earth, the shadow's width is close to $2r$. Let $t$ be the time it takes the mid-point of the Moon to cross the center of the shadow, about 3 hours (in eclipses of the longest duration, when the Moon crosses the center of the shadow).

Assume the Moon moves around Earth at some constant speed. If it needs time $T$ to cover $2\pi R \approx 6.28R$, and time $t$ to cover $2r$, then

$$6.28 R / 2 r     =     T/t$$

From this Aristarchus obtained: $R/r \approx     60$

Comment: Where do you get numbers to plug in for $T$ and $t$?

Comment: The article I linked states that T is one month, and t is 3 hours. Unless I'm not reading it correctly?

Comment: x @user: You're ignoring the word "about" in both places. Those are extremely rough values. With that kind of precision, ending up with rounding errors of about 10% shouldn't surprise anyone.

Comment: In fact, due to the eccentricity of the Moon's orbit, the duration of an eclipse where the Moon crosses the center of the shadow can be as much as 12% shorter or longer than the average time, depending whether it happens close to apogee or perigee.

Answer (score 0):

According to this article on [Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/On_the_Sizes_and_Distances_(Aristarchus)#Lunar_eclipse), [Aristarchus](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Aristarchus_of_Samos) actually got a value of $20$.

You are not alone, however;

> A similar procedure was later used by [Hipparchus](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hipparchus), who estimated the mean distance to the moon as 67 Earth radii, and [Ptolemy](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ptolemy), who took 59 Earth radii for this value.

Comment: Mmm, according to a paragraph below, it should be 80 Earth radii. Was Archimedes wrong? I need to be sure of the right value for an article I'm writing. Thanks in advance!

Comment: @Unix; if you carry on reading, it explains 'The disagreement of the work with Archimedes seems to be due to its taking an Aristarchus statement that the lunisolar diameter is 1/15 of a "meros" of the zodiac to mean 1/15 of a zodiacal sign (30°), unaware that the Greek word "meros" meant either "portion" or 7°1/2; and 1/15 of the latter amount is 1°/2, in agreement with Archimedes' testimony.'